# Is there any way to toggle css class in html element with ternary operator?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add some css class on list items every time it's clicked. For example, I've got menu and I need to put "active" class to menu item if it's selected. Is it possible to do with ternary operator?

I tried to add it to class attribute inside of list, but it seems to not be working.

This is what I have tried:

```
<li class="regular (('active') ? 'regular' : 'regular active')">Home</li>
```

I expect 'active' class to be added to list when it's selected, but it doesn't work.

Comment: You can't use ternary operators with HTML only unless i missed something :o

Comment: you can do sth like that in react (jsx) - 'conditional rendering'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should bind a click handler, and toggle the class "active" on/off inside that click handler:

```js
document.querySelector("li").addEventListener("click", function () {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
});
```

```css
li.active { background: yellow; }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="regular">Home</li>
</ul>
```

When you have more than one such `li` element:

```js
for (const li of document.querySelectorAll("li")) {
    li.addEventListener("click", function () {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
    });
}
```

```css
li.active { background: yellow; }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="regular">Home</li>
    <li class="regular">Other</li>
</ul>
```

If the "active" class should only exist on one `li` at a time, then:

```js
for (const li of document.querySelectorAll("li")) {
    li.addEventListener("click", function () {
        const active = document.querySelector("li.active");
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        if (active && this !== active) active.classList.toggle("active");
    });
}
```

```css
li.active { background: yellow; }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="regular">Home</li>
    <li class="regular">Other</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution of your question !!! using jquery plugin

```
 $('ul').on('click', 'li a', function() {
    $('ul li a.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Using Javascript you can solve the same problem.

```
function myFunction(e) {
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".active");
  [].forEach.call(elems, function(el) {
    el.classList.remove("active");
  });
  e.target.className = "active";
}
```

html Goes here

```
   <ul>
      <li ><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
      <li ><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
   </ul>
```

css goes here

```
li a.active{ 
  color:red;
}
```

Comment: Why You devote my answer before devoting please play with your editor just copy the code.